# Has CockroachDB implemented Row Level Security?

Tags: database, cockroachdb

Regarding https://forum.cockroachlabs.com/t/row-level-security-with-multi-tenancy/1294/2 - I can't find anything in the docs whether it's been implemented in later versions.

Ideally, if anyone can confirm this has been implemented, and where the docs are, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of v21.1, Row-level Security is not a supported feature in CockroachDB.

However, Role-based Access Control which is mentioned in that forum post has been implemented and there are [docs available](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/cockroachcloud/user-authorization#use-roles) for that feature.